# Silverlight PivotViewer Semantic Zoom Two PivotViewerTemplates Displayed Simultaneously

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0, pivotviewer, semantic-zoom

I am using a PivotViewer control in a Silverlight 5 User Control.  I have two PivotViewerTemplates defined to take advantage of Semantic Zoom.  The first template defined has a MaxWidth of 300, the second template has no MaxWidth set.  At a certain "zoom" within the PivotViewer control, both PivotViewerTemplates are being displayed simultaneously (both templates are somewhat transparent at that time as well).  It is almost as if it is stuck between transitioning from one PivotViewerTemplate to the other.

How can I prevent both PivotViewerTempaltes from being displayed simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the transition effect between two templates. When doing a large scale transition it provides a smooth animation. However, it can be a bit sticky depending your MaxWidth and the number of items in your collection.

You will find that if you play with the MaxWidth you can minimize the effect for your collection.